# Get data by array selector

Tags: javascript

I want to get data from a data array by an array selector:

```
var sel = ["node1"]["node2"]["node3"];
var my_data = data_array[sel] //?!?
```

How to get a correct my_data?

Comment: show data array structure please

Comment: What is sel expected to look like? "node1node2node3" or "node1, node2, node3"?

Comment: the "sel" structure is always different, it depends on "data_array".

Comment: it should work like: var my_data = data_array["node1"]["node2"]["node3"];

Answer (score 1):

What about this idea?

```
Object.prototype.getBySelector = function(selector) {
    var currentElement = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) 
        currentElement = currentElement[selector[i]];
    return currentElement;
}

var sel = ["node1","node2","node3"];
var my_data = data_array.getBySelector(sel);
```

You can easily extend the getBySelector function by checking, if the nodes are existing and returning null, so no exception is thrown on an invalid selector.

See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U8YDQ/

Comment: thats very nice. But expensive for my needs, since there is much data to process.

Answer (score 0):

Its a wild-wild guess. You can try [**eval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
var sel = '["node1"]["node2"]["node3"]';
var my_data = eval('data_array' + sel);
```

Comment: i think this would work. I try not to use eval(). So i will do a workaround.

Comment: @bergman, it works see http://jsfiddle.net/U8YDQ/2/. And do share what is your workaround

Comment: Hi thx for the fiddle. My workaround is passing the "data_array" around: var my_data = data_array["node1"]["node2"]["node3"]; :)